# Increase Report Size From 64 bytes to 256 bytes CUSTOM USB HID?

Tags: usb, stm32, hid

I want to transfer 256 bytes from host to stm32f103 device over USB Custom HID interface

Currently, 64 bytes Read/Write is Working

Following is the Report Descriptor in my stm32:

/** Usb HID report descriptor. */

```
static uint8_t CUSTOM_HID_ReportDesc_FS[USBD_CUSTOM_HID_REPORT_DESC_SIZE] __ALIGN_END ={   
 0x06,0x00,0xFF,                        //Usage Page 0xff00
   0x09, 0x01,                  //USAGE (Pointer)
   0xA1,0x01,                   //Collection (application)
      //Input Report
      0x19,0x01,                 //Usage Minimum
      0x29,0x40,                 //Usage Minimum
      0x15,0x00,                 //Logical Minimum
      0x26,0xFF,0x00,            //Logical Minimum
      0x75,0x08,                 //report size : 8-bit field size
      0x95, CUSTOM_HID_EPIN_SIZE,//Report count
      0x81,0x02,                 //Input (data, array, Abs)   
      //Output Report
      0x19,0x01,                 //usage Minimum
      0x29,0x40,                 //usage Minimum
      0x75,0x08,                 //report size : 8-bit field size
      0x95,CUSTOM_HID_EPOUT_SIZE,//Report Count
      0x91,0x02,                 //Output (data, array, Abs)
  0xC0                           //END_COLLECTION              
};
```

If, I am changing the CUSTOM_HID_EPIN_SIZE,CUSTOM_HID_EPOUT_SIZE to 256, my USB device is not recognized.

I need some help to modify the report descriptor to support 256 byte transfer

Thanks

Comment: You will need to change the report count items to be 0x96 0x00 0x01 because your increased length value can no longer be represented in a single byte.

Comment: Do not increase EP size above 64 bytes. This is limit for  Full Speed device, you violate the USB spec and host refuses to play with your device.

Comment: @ddbug Yeah you are right , i asked the same in STM Community. 64 bytes is the Full Speed Limit. I have to switch to High Speed to get the same but the CPU only supports Full Speed.Thanks for the answer.